# Positional Association of variable number of arguments in Node JS for better error message construct

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a variable number of arguments routine for better error messages with the context.

I am looking for a JavaScript solution that can run in NodeJS.

Let me first explain my requirement with code:

> In file licenseNotificationMessages.js

```
const licenseNotificationMessages = {
    CapacityAlmostExpired:{
        description: ​'my description contains $1 followed by $2 followed by $3 in this case.,
    },
    CapacityExpired:{
       description: ​'my description contains $1 followed by $2 in this case.,
    },
}
const constructMessage = (message, ...var_args_array) => {
    // TODO. Replace the message's occurrences of $1, $2, $3 ... $N by var_args_array[0], 
    // var_args_array[1], .... var_args_array[N].
}

module.exports = {
    licenseNotificationMessages,
    constructMessage,
}
```

I want to use it something like:

> In another file exporting licenseNotificationMessages

```
const { licenseNotificationMessages, constructMessage } = require('./licenseNotificationMessages');

description = licenseNotificationMessages.constructMessage(licenseNotificationMessages.CapacityAlmostExpired.description, ['val_for_$1', 'val_for_$2', 'val_for_$3']);

......
description = licenseNotificationMessages.constructMessage(licenseNotificationMessages.CapacityExpired.description, ['val_for_$1', 'val_for_$2']);
```

Not getting any clue how to achieve it in JavaScript in Node JS environment. (I am in node 16+).

Any pointer will be helpful here.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use error constructors for this: `export class CapacityAlmostExpiredError extends Error { ... }` `const error = new CapacityAlmostExpiredError(...args);`. Arguably, this is more maintainable.

Comment: Returning to your question, what do you want to happen if the size of the arguments list does not match the number of string placeholders?

Comment: That's an 'underlying assumption' (well: will document) that this two should match. Otherwise behavior 'undefined' J. Of course would love to know if a better way to handle this errorneous case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Error classes

In my opinion, defining a few error classes is often the best solution when having different errors with different messages:

```
export class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(`Some message with ${args[0]} and ${args[1]} mentioned in it`);
  };
}

export class CapacityAlmostExpiredError extends Error {
  constructor(capacityUsed, capacityLimit) {
    super(`Used capacity (${capacityUsed} MB) almost exceeds the limit of ${capacityLimit} MB`);
  };
}
```

## `console.log` with placeholders

`console.log` has a pretty elegant API for this case, - but it doesn't go without major downsides (more on them later):

```js
console.log(messageWithPlaceholders, ...args);
```

[image]

In your case it would be:

```js
const message = "my description contains %s followed by %s followed by %s in this case."; // notice lack of numbers

console.log(message, 'val_for_the_first_%s', 'val_for_the_second_%s', 'val_for_the_third_%s');
```

#### The downsides:

- this is logging, not string creation, - you don't have any access to the string before it is logged;
- `console.log` is often forbidden in production code;
- you have to change placeholder patterns to %, instead of $;

## Iterating arguments

With all that said, if the `constructMessage` approach is strictly necessary for whatever reason, you would have to iterate the arguments list, get an index of each argument, convert the index into a placeholder, find this placeholder in the string, and replace it with the argument's value:

```js
function constructMessage(string, args) {
  let message = string;

  for (const [ index, arg ] of args.entries()) {
    const placeholder = "$" + (index + 1); // 0 becomes '$1'

    message = message.replace(placeholder, arg);
  }

  return message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I agree, Approach-1 of different classes are better. But engineers are lazy, they may like approach-2 J.

Comment: You're welcome! I wouldn't recommend the second approach though, - see the downsides I have just added